# Issue Installing Sitecore 9.1 without self -signed certificate

Tags: installation

Trying to install Sitecore 9.1 on environment with following servers:

• CMS which will have Processing, Reporting, Identity too
• CD
• xConnect
• Solr
• SQL Servers 2016

As per the policy, we can’t install Self Signed certificates hence we received the SSL certificates that are already installed on the servers. Now while proceeding ahead with installation we are getting issues like certificate for Identity will not be created.

Please help us resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you using SIF 2.0? Have you commented out the code which is responsible for creating the certs?

Comment: Yes , I know  but self sign certificate is blocked by the client. i want to know how to install without self sign certificate